# Como utilizar lib do github no meu projeto Android Studio?

Tags: github, lib

estou precisando utilizar uma lib para dar zoom na imageview do Android Studio, após algumas pesquisas, encontrei uma lib no github que pode me ajudar, porém não consegui usá-la no meu projeto, alguém me explica como utilizar o github no meu projeto? Sou novo na área e estou conhecendo agora o github. Eu importei o projeto baixado porém ele abre como um novo projeto independente, aí não consegui usar nada.

Comment: normalmente na pagina da mesma tem um tutorial, procure por vídeos no youtube tem muitos sobre isso, de como usar essas apis...

Comment: Qual o nome dessa lib? Veja se ela não está declarada dentro do bloco `dependencies` no arquivo `build.gradle` do projeto que você baixou do Github. Se estiver, basta você copiar a declaração para o arquivo `build.gradle` do seu projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente como qualquer outra biblioteca (ou a maioria delas pelo menos). Adicionando no build.gradle do nível app do seu projeto, a [página de desenvolvedores](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/?hl=pt-br) do android explica como utilizar o gradle.

Um exemplo:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

android{
    ...
}

dependencies{

    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' //Isso adiciona a biblioteca de suporte do android ao projeto

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3' //Isso adiciona a biblioteca do jsoup ao projeto

}
```

Lembre-se que depois de adicionar items ao seu build.gradle ou qualquer outra alteração você deve sincronizar seu build.gradle com o projeto

Comment: Obrigado cara, ajudou aqui... Consegui lendo na pagina do desenvolvedor